# How to generate a tree view from this result set based on Tree Traversal Algorithm?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, html, modified-preorder-tree-t

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `category_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `root_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lft` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rht` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
  KEY `lft` (`lft`,`rht`),
  KEY `root_id` (`root_id`)
)
```

Based on this question: 
[Getting a modified preorder tree traversal model (nested set) into a <ul>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310649/getting-a-modified-preorder-tree-traversal-model-nested-set-into-a-ul)

The difference is that I have many trees in one table. Each row has a foreign key representing its parent and its top parent: category_id and root_id. Also I have the lft and rht fields based on this example:
http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/2

Based on this rows:

```
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(1, NULL, NULL, 'Fruits', 1, 14);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(2, 1, 1, 'Apple', 2, 3);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(3, 1, 1, 'Orange', 4, 9);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(4, 3, 1, 'Orange Type 1', 5, 6);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(5, 3, 1, 'Orange Type 2', 7, 8);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(6, 1, 1, 'Pear', 10, 11);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(7, 1, 1, 'Banana', 12, 13);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(8, NULL, NULL, 'Eletronics', 1, 14);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(9, 8, 8, 'Cell Phones', 2, 3);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(10, 8, 8, 'Computers', 4, 9);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(11, 10, 8, 'PC', 5, 6);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(12, 10, 8, 'MAC', 7, 8);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(13, 8, 8, 'Printers', 10, 11);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(14, 8, 8, 'Cameras', 12, 13);
```

How can I build an ordened list representing this tree?

With the sql bellow:

```
SELECT c. * , (COUNT( p.id ) -1) AS depth
FROM `categorias` AS p
CROSS JOIN categories AS c
WHERE (
c.lft
BETWEEN p.lft
AND p.rht
)
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.lft;
```

I got this result:

[image]

As you can see, I need to order by root_id too, so that I can generate the correct tree.

Also, after get the tree, is there a way to order each node by name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

All you need to do is set root_id to the top parents too, so that you can ORDER BY correctly.

With the query bellow I can have separeted trees, and uptade only the tree that I'm working on:

```
SELECT c . * , count( p.id ) AS depth
FROM `categories` c
CROSS JOIN categories p
WHERE (
c.lft
BETWEEN p.lft
AND p.rht
)
AND c.root_id = p.root_id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.root_id, c.lft
```

Answer (score 2):

> As you can see, I need to order by root_id too, so that I can generate the correct tree.

When building the nested tree model, never make duplicates on `lft` and `rgt`. In fact, you should declare them unique.

In you data model, the sets for category `1` and `8` overlap. Say, `1` to `14` are used both for items `1` and `8`.

Replace them with these values:

```
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(1, NULL, NULL, 'Fruits', 1, 14);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(2, 1, 1, 'Apple', 2, 3);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(3, 1, 1, 'Orange', 4, 9);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(4, 3, 1, 'Orange Type 1', 5, 6);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(5, 3, 1, 'Orange Type 2', 7, 8);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(6, 1, 1, 'Pear', 10, 11);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(7, 1, 1, 'Banana', 12, 13);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(8, NULL, NULL, 'Eletronics', 15, 29);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(9, 8, 8, 'Cell Phones', 16, 17);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(10, 8, 8, 'Computers', 19, 24);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(11, 10, 8, 'PC', 20, 21);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(12, 10, 8, 'MAC', 22, 23);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(13, 8, 8, 'Printers', 25, 26);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(14, 8, 8, 'Cameras', 27, 28);
```

Now you don't have to order on `root_id`.

> Also, after get the tree, is there a way to order each node by name?

No easy way, unless you insert the nodes in the name order from the beginning. Siblings with the greater `name` should have greater `lft` and `rgt`:

```
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(1, NULL, NULL, 'Fruits', 1, 14);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(2, 1, 1, 'Apple', 2, 3);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(7, 1, 1, 'Banana', 4, 5);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(3, 1, 1, 'Orange', 6, 11);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(4, 3, 1, 'Orange Type 1', 7, 8);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(5, 3, 1, 'Orange Type 2', 9, 10);
INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES(6, 1, 1, 'Pear', 12, 13);
```

A nested tree can only have one implicit order.

There is also a way to query adjacency list in `MySQL`:

- [**Hierarchical queries in MySQL**](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/)

, however, you will have to create an additional unique ordering column if you want to order on anything else than `id`.

You may also want to read this article:

- [**Adjacency list vs. nested sets: MySQL**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/29/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-mysql/)

which shows how to store and query nested sets more efficiently.

Comment: Thanks, I will read this and try. Although, I was wondering if there isn't a way to keep repeated lft and rht since I have a way do distinguish (root_id). I already achieved an query with something like: WHERE root_id =1 OR id =1 ORDER BY lft to get one of the trees (but not all). This is really the wrong way? Also I have the root_id for reference when using the rebuild_tree() method listed on this link http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/3 So, everything is working properly except the SELECT for ordened lists.

Comment: If I follow your steps, how can I change the rebuild_tree() function to rebuild just one tree and not all? Since I will remove root_id?

Comment: If you always separate the trees (like with `WHERE root_id = 1`) it's OK to allow overlapping between different sets. But your original query mixed two trees. To rebuild only one tree, just call `rebuild_tree(1)` or `rebuild_tree(8)`, this will only rebuild the trees starting from `1` or `8`.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I'm doing with rebuild_tree($root_id). But, is there a way to continue with this aproach and change my select query so that I can get the whole result separeted by trees, I mean, root_id? Today I can't achieve it because I don't know how to specify this in the query: ORDER BY lft "but group by trees"

Comment: @Keyne: try `ORDER BY root_id, lft`. If you always place `Electronics` items after `Fruits` items, mere `ORDER BY lft` will suffice.

Comment: + 1 for the ORDER BY, thanks. I also have added WHERE c.root_id =p.root_id and now all records are set with root_id, even the top parent. Now everything is working properly.