# How to change this CROSS JOIN SQL created for a tree traversal (nested set)?

Tags: sql, mysql, nested-sets, modified-preorder-tree-t

In the query below there is a field called `main` which is used to differentiate the categories.
So, there are common categories and main categories and both can be found on a tree. The `main` field is just a type and there's nothing with the tree structure, I mean, it's like a status field.

```
  SELECT `c`.*, 
           (count(p.id)-1) AS `depth` 
      FROM `categories` AS `c` 
  CROSS JOIN `categories` AS `p` 
     WHERE (c.lft BETWEEN p.lft AND p.rht) 
       AND (c.root_id =p.root_id) 
       AND (p.main =1) 
  GROUP BY `c`.`id` 
  ORDER BY `c`.`root_id` ASC, `c`.`lft` ASC
```

There is a `where` clausule which specify that the parent category need to be a main category. Also, sometimes I need to do a `select` where the parent category is a common category `p.main =0`.

The `depth` is the position of the element in the tree. So if a category is a one level children of another, the depth will be `1`, if two levels, the depth will be `2`.

My problem is that when I do the select above, if there are children marked as common category on a tree where the father is a main category (selecting `p.main =1`) the common categories `depth` is always `0`.

In other words, the select works properly, if I select all categories that has the top parent marked as `main`, it will display the tree with all categories including children categories marked with `main=0`. But in this case, the depth is always `0`

See the results:

[image]

The category `1423` is a child of `27` and is not a main category, but `27` is, so depth is `0`, but need to be `1`. The category `276` is a child of `64` and both are a main categories, so it has the right depth.

How can I change this query so that the `depth` field work as expected?

Reference here: [How to generate a tree view from this result set based on Tree Traversal Algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638551/how-to-generate-a-tree-view-from-this-result-set-based-on-tree-traversal-algorith)

Comment: The words 'nested set' would help here.

Comment: Do you want 'depth' to equal the number oF ancestors this element has?  Do you want this to run for only nodes that have an ancestor that is a 'main' node?  Do you want it to only count ancestors that are 'main'? Because it's hard to tell from your question.

Comment: @ijw See my edit and tell me if it's clear now

Answer (score 0):

You actually say you're looking for this count but only for nodes what are children of a main parent.  If that's what you truly want then your query is more wrong than just fixing that - the table you call 'p' and seem to think is a 'parent' table is actually an '*ancestor*' table - similarly 'c' is not child but '*descendant*'.  You end up counting `main`-flagged ancestors of all nodes in the tree.

Comment: I didn't get the point. Everything work prolerly when all the categories involved are main or common. Can you clarify? There are a cross join with group by. So, the count works even if the category has no childrens. And Yes, parent is the ancestor and not a main parent. The main filed has another purpose. It's like a type.