# Preorder traversal parent-child dynamic insertion not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following database:

```
id  name            unit_id lft rgt level
--  --------------  ------- --- --- -----
1   Company Name    1       1   2   0
2   Manager         2       2   9   1
3   HR              3       3   8   2
4   Jr.Manager      5       5   8   2
5   Sr.Manager      8       7   8   2
```

I want to insert record in the above preorder traversal table. For that I used the following code and queries:

```
function addstructure() {
        $level = $_GET['level'] + 1;
        $rgt = $_GET['rgt'] + 1;
        if ($_GET['level'] == 0) {
            $sql = "UPDATE xp_subunit SET lft = lft+2, rgt=rgt+2 WHERE rgt > " . $_GET['rgt'] . "; ";
            $this->db->query($sql);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO xp_subunit SET level=" . $level . ", lft =" . $_GET['rgt'] . ", rgt =  " . $rgt . " , name = '" . $_GET['name'] . "', unit_id='" . $_GET['unit_id'] . "', description='" . $_GET['description'] . "';";
            $this->db->query($sql);
        } else {
            $sql = "UPDATE xp_subunit SET rgt = rgt+2 WHERE rgt > " . $_GET['lft'] . "; ";
            $this->db->query($sql);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO xp_subunit SET level=" . $level . ", lft =" . $_GET['rgt'] . ", rgt =  " . $rgt . " , name = '" . $_GET['name'] . "', unit_id='" . $_GET['unit_id'] . "', description='" . $_GET['description'] . "';";
            echo $this->db->query($sql);
        }
    }
```

I am getting lft, rgt and level from database. The problem is when I tried to insert record ex. Jr.Manager and Sr.Manager under Manager category, it is not inserted properly. Instead of "Manager" category its inserting under HR->Jr.Manager->Sr.Manager like. 
Whats wrong with above code?

Here is the image for better understanding:

[image: Here is the image for better understanding:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am slightly modified your code just try this:

```
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $rgt = $_GET['rgt'];
    $lft = $_GET['lft'];
    $level = $_GET['level'] + 1;
    $right = $rgt + 1;

    $sql1 = "UPDATE xp_subunit SET lft = lft+2 WHERE lft >= $rgt ;";
    $this->db->query($sql1);
    $sql2 = "UPDATE xp_subunit SET rgt = rgt+2 WHERE rgt >= $rgt ;";
    $this->db->query($sql2);
    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO xp_subunit (`id`,`name`,`unit_id`,`lft`, `rgt`, `level`)        
values (NULL, '$name', '$unit_id',$rgt, $right, '$level');";
    echo $this->db->query($sql3);
```

It will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You begin with stating that 'level' is whatever level you get from the get-request plus one. It always increments your level, so it puts jr. manager under HR and sr. manager under jr. manager.

Is it necessary to increment the level from your get-request?