# How to display and properly indent a tree structure

Tags: php, tree

DB structure is this:

```
INSERT INTO categories (title, lft, rgt) VALUES ('Cat 1',1,16);
INSERT INTO categories (title, lft, rgt) VALUES ('Cat 2',2,3);
INSERT INTO categories (title, lft, rgt) VALUES ('Cat 3',4,7);
INSERT INTO categories (title, lft, rgt) VALUES ('Cat 4',5,6);
INSERT INTO categories (title, lft, rgt) VALUES ('Cat 5',8,13);
INSERT INTO categories (title, lft, rgt) VALUES ('Cat 6',9,12);
INSERT INTO categories (title, lft, rgt) VALUES ('Cat 7',10,11);
INSERT INTO categories (title, lft, rgt) VALUES ('Cat 8',14,15);
```

When I run this query:

```
SELECT n.title, COUNT(*)-1 AS depth FROM categories AS n, categories AS p WHERE  n.lft BETWEEN p.lft AND p.rgt GROUP BY n.lft ORDER BY n.lft;

$result = mysql_query($query);

// Build array
$tree = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $tree[] = $row;
}
```

After that I can use following function:

```
// bootstrap loop
    $result = '';
    $currDepth = -1;  // -1 to get the outer <ul>
    while (!empty($tree)) {
      $currNode = array_shift($tree);
      // Level down?
      if ($currNode['depth'] > $currDepth) {
        // Yes, open <ul>
        $result .= '<ul>';
      }
      // Level up?
      if ($currNode['depth'] < $currDepth) {
        // Yes, close n open <ul>
        $result .= str_repeat('</ul>', $currDepth - $currNode['depth']);
      }
      // Always add node
      $result .= '<li>' . $currNode['title'] . '</li>';
      // Adjust current depth
      $currDepth = $currNode['depth'];
      // Are we finished?
      if (empty($tree)) {
        // Yes, close n open <ul>
        $result .= str_repeat('</ul>', $currDepth + 1);
      }
    }

    print $result;
```

Can anyone tell me how to print above tree **WITHOUT** `<ul> and <li>.`. 
I want to print it using `&nbsp;` intended for child and sub-child... because I have to put it in `<select>` list and in other HTML tags

The structure I am using can be seen here:  [Getting a modified preorder tree traversal model (nested set) into a <ul>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310649/getting-a-modified-preorder-tree-traversal-model-nested-set-into-a-ul)

Comment: Just a hint: when a problem is that urgent, take at least the time to right a good title for your question.

Comment: what if u replace <ul> with &nbsp; and <li> with &nbsp;&nbsp; for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an urgent response (and untested), because you already have the `depth` of each element/node, you could use that for how many `&nbsp;` blocks to output for each one, and then end each line with a `<br />` (unless you need to separate elements by some other means).

Try a function to output the spaces and it should be something as simple as this:

```
function _tab($depth) {
    $tabs = '';
    while ($depth-- > 0) $tabs .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    return $tabs;
}

// bootstrap loop
$result = '';
while (!empty($tree)) {
    $currNode = array_shift($tree);
    $result .= _tab($currNode['depth']) . $currNode['title'] . '<br />';
}

print $result;
```

Comment: Works like charm. Thank you very very much @newfurniturey .. just one correction i needed to make was :

$result **.=** _tab($currNode['depth']) . $currNode['title'] . '<br />';

just added this: .=

Comment: Can you please explain the meaning of this:  while ($depth-- > 0) ??

Comment: @user1713941 In plain english, it means "While the depth is greater than 0, add the `&nbsp;` code to the tabs-variable, subtract `1` from the depth, and repeat.". So, if `$depth` starts at `1`, it will execute one time; if it starts at `2`, it will execute twice, etc.

Comment: can you please look at this thread and reply buddy? @newfurniturey http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706430/how-to-display-and-properly-indent-a-tree-structure-of-a-single-node .. thank you so much