# How to display and properly indent a tree structure of a single node?

Tags: php

The DB structure is as follows:

```
    cat_ID| cat_name    | cat_nicename  | lft | rgt 
    _________________________________________________
    287   | Wallpapers  |  wallpapers   | 61  | 62
    1656  | Gadget      |  gadget       | 63  | 64
    1958  | Sms         |  sms          | 65  | 66
    2901  | fun         |  fun          | 67  | 68
    4419  | Joke        |  joke         | 69  | 70
    4775  | health      |  health       | 71  | 72
    5098  | Mobile      |  mobile       | 73  | 90
    5100  | TV          |  tv           | 91  | 92
    5101  | Main        |  main         | 93  | 94
    5102  | Nokia       |  nokia        | 76  | 83
    5103  | Samsung     |  samsung      | 84  | 87
    5104  | Micromax    |  micromax     | 88  | 89
    5105  | Nokia Sub 1 |  nokiasub1    | 77  | 78
    5106  | Nokia Sub 2 |  nokiasub2    | 79  | 82
    5107  | Nokia Sub 3 |  nokiasub3    | 80  | 81
    5109  | Galaxy      |  galaxy       | 85  | 86
```

The Folloing query I am using to get One category and all it's subcats:

```
$sql = "SELECT n.cat_ID,n.cat_name,n.cat_nicename, (COUNT(*)-1)
 AS depth FROM " .TBL_CATEGORIES. " AS n, " .TBL_CATEGORIES. " AS p
  WHERE p.cat_nicename='mobile'
 AND n.lft BETWEEN p.lft AND p.rgt
 GROUP BY n.lft ORDER BY n.lft;";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$tree = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $tree[] = $row;
}

function _tab($depth) {
    $tabs = '';
    while ($depth-- > 0) $tabs .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    return $tabs;
}

// bootstrap loop
$result = '';
while (!empty($tree)) {
    $currNode = array_shift($tree);
    $result .= _tab($currNode['depth']) . $currNode['cat_name'] . $currNode['depth'].'<br />';
}

print $result;
```

if i do not use `p.cat_nicename='mobile'`, by the above code, tree structure displays perfect, but if i want to retrieve just one node by using `p.cat_nicename='mobile'` All the depth I am getting is `'0'` hence it is NOT putting any `&nbsp;` and displaying flat tree under `'mobile'`.. if i query just `"mobile"` it should display like:

```
Mobile
    Nokia
        Nokia Sub 1
        Nokia Sub 2
            Nokia Sub 3
    Samsung
        Galaxy
    Micromax
```

so my questions are:

1. **How can I display Tree of a particular node?**
2. **How can I display just all the root categories only? no childs no sub, by using single SQL query?**

Comment: Hi @newfurniturey if you have time.. can you please look at it? Many thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. After looking through the table structure and query, I don't think
   there is a way to select a tree of a particular node without an
   additional sub-query (I may be wrong, but this is the only way I
   could get it to work while testing). To do this, I would suggest
   adding a sub-query into the `FROM` clause as if you're selecting
   from a 3rd-table. Then, add an extra `BETWEEN` condition in your
   `WHERE` clause to test it.

   Something like this:

   ```
   SELECT
       n.cat_ID, n.cat_name, n.cat_nicename, COUNT(*)-1 AS depth
   FROM
       categories AS n,
       categories AS p,
       (SELECT lft, rgt FROM categories WHERE cat_nicename = 'mobile') AS q
   WHERE
       n.lft BETWEEN p.lft AND p.rgt
       AND p.lft BETWEEN q.lft AND q.rgt
   GROUP BY n.lft
   ORDER BY n.lft;
   ```

   Using this, you would need to add all of the logic handling "which"
   node you want to get a tree for in the sub-query. The first two
   tables (`n` and `p`) are selected-from as normal. This is required
   to get the proper `depth` values. *Then*, it compares `p` and `q` -
   but `q` is already limited. So, once you have the proper `depth`
   values you then limit it to only the categories you want.
2. To display all of the root categories only is far easier. Using your
   query, the definition of a "root category" is one that has `depth =
   0`. If you use MySQL's [`HAVING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) clause, you can easily check it
   with `HAVING depth = 0`. Try the following:

   ```
   SELECT
       n.cat_ID, n.cat_name, n.cat_nicename, COUNT(*)-1 AS depth
   FROM
       categories AS n,
       categories AS p
   WHERE
       n.lft BETWEEN p.lft AND p.rgt
   GROUP BY n.lft
   HAVING depth = 0
   ORDER BY n.lft;
   ```

Comment: Works perfect.. @newfurniturey Thank you is a very small word for the people like you. Love and Regards

Comment: Buddy.. @newfurniturey one quick question if you can answer: how can i get the value of NEXT depth in bootstrap loop? like $currNode['depth'] it is a current depth.. how will i get next depth value?